# DataGrid with columns created dynamically from the items in nested collection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpf-controls

I have to create a table [that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHPWW.png) - there is a fixed set of columns that are bound to properties of the items from a collection set as DataGrid's ItemsSource, but there also have to be dynamic columns that are created based on the number of items in the nested collection (collection inside previously mentioned collection).

The number of items in these nested collections will be the same for every item in the main collection. Additionally, once the instance of `MainData` is created, the number of items in the nested collection won't change. Also, their `Name` properties will be the same (headers of the dynamic columns should be bound to them), only the values of `Value` properties will be different and can change when the main object's values are recalculated.

Here's how the classes look like:

```
public class MainData
{
    public ValueWithName Property1 { get; }
    public ValueWithName Property2 { get; }
    public ValueWithName Property3 { get; }
    public ValueWithName Property4 { get; }
    
    public ICollection<ValueWithName> NestedData { get; }
}

public class ValueWithName
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Value { get; }
}
```

In my viewmodel I have a collection similar to the one below:

```
public ObservableCollection<MainData> DataCollection { get; }
```

In the view I created all of the fixed columns as DataGridTextColumn:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Property1.Name}" Binding="{Binding Property1.Value}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Property2.Name}" Binding="{Binding Property2.Value}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Property3.Name}" Binding="{Binding Property3.Value}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Property4.Name}" Binding="{Binding Property4.Value}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now the question is: is it possible to create these dynamic columns using described structure? I've looked through many similar posts here and over the web, but none of them matched my requirements. Until now I've tried a few different approaches (e.g. attached behaviors) but without success.

Comment: Your task contains a conceptual logical problem.
The number of additional columns is determined by the number of items in the NestedData collection.
But this collection can have a different number of elements for each row and, what is even more complicated, the number of elements in it can change dynamically.
In general, such a task will be extremely difficult to solve.
Perhaps you can simplify it somehow to begin with.

Comment: Is may be `ListView` with specified `GridView` control that you need. See [`GridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/gridview-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: @EldHasp Unfortunately, it was requested to look like this, but there are some details that I should mention right away, which could simplify this a bit, I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use the DataTable instead of the collection `public ObservableCollection <MainData> DataCollection {get; }`.

I will also suggest an option for your ViewModel implementation.
See how much it suits you.
It uses columns auto-generation .
There is no error handling in it, so if the collection is of a different type, or is empty, there will be an exception.

Your classes with added constructors and ViewModels:

```
namespace DataGridDynamic
{
    public class ValueWithName
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public string Value { get; }

        public ValueWithName(string name, string value)
        {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace DataGridDynamic
{
    public class MainData
    {
        public ValueWithName Property1 { get; }
        public ValueWithName Property2 { get; }
        public ValueWithName Property3 { get; }
        public ValueWithName Property4 { get; }

        public IReadOnlyList<ValueWithName> NestedData { get; }

        public MainData(ValueWithName property1,
                        ValueWithName property2,
                        ValueWithName property3,
                        ValueWithName property4,
                        IEnumerable<ValueWithName> nestedData)
        {
            Property1 = property1;
            Property2 = property2;
            Property3 = property3;
            Property4 = property4;
            NestedData = nestedData.ToList().AsReadOnly();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace DataGridDynamic
{

    public class MainDataViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MainData> DataCollection { get; }
            = new ObservableCollection<MainData>()
            {
                new MainData(
                    new ValueWithName("Name1","12345"),
                    new ValueWithName("Name2","qweret"),
                    new ValueWithName("Name3","asdfg"),
                    new ValueWithName("Name4","zxcvb"),
                    new ValueWithName[] 
                    {
                        new ValueWithName("NestedName1","12345"),
                        new ValueWithName("NestedName2","qweret")
                    }
                ),
                new MainData(
                    new ValueWithName("Name1","0878"),
                    new ValueWithName("Name2","iupuip"),
                    new ValueWithName("Name3","jklkj"),
                    new ValueWithName("Name4","bnmn"),
                    new ValueWithName[] 
                    {
                        new ValueWithName("NestedName1","rtyt"),
                        new ValueWithName("NestedName2","fgfdfgf")
                    }
                ),
            };
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridDynamic.DataGridDynamicWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridDynamic"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DataGridDynamicWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid DataContext="{DynamicResource viewModel}">
        <FrameworkElement.Resources>
            <local:MainDataViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
        </FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"
                  AutoGeneratedColumns="OnAutoGeneratedColumns"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace DataGridDynamic
{
    public partial class DataGridDynamicWindow : Window
    {
        public DataGridDynamicWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
            IList<MainData> list = (IList<MainData>)dataGrid.ItemsSource;
            MainData mainData = list[0];
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case "Property1":
                    e.Column = new DataGridTextColumn()
                    {
                        Header = mainData.Property1.Name,
                        Binding = new Binding($"{nameof(MainData.Property1)}.{nameof(ValueWithName.Value)}")
                    };
                    break;
                case "Property2":
                    e.Column = new DataGridTextColumn()
                    {
                        Header = mainData.Property2.Name,
                        Binding = new Binding($"{nameof(MainData.Property2)}.{nameof(ValueWithName.Value)}")
                    };
                    break;
                case "Property3":
                    e.Column = new DataGridTextColumn()
                    {
                        Header = mainData.Property3.Name,
                        Binding = new Binding($"{nameof(MainData.Property3)}.{nameof(ValueWithName.Value)}")
                    };
                    break;
                case "Property4":
                    e.Column = new DataGridTextColumn()
                    {
                        Header = mainData.Property4.Name,
                        Binding = new Binding($"{nameof(MainData.Property4)}.{nameof(ValueWithName.Value)}")
                    };
                    break;
                default:
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void OnAutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
            IList<MainData> list = (IList<MainData>)dataGrid.ItemsSource;
            MainData mainData = list[0];

            var columns = dataGrid.Columns;
            for (int i = 0; i < mainData.NestedData.Count; i++)
            {
                ValueWithName nameValue = mainData.NestedData[i];
                columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
                {
                    Header = nameValue.Name,
                    Binding = new Binding($"{nameof(MainData.NestedData)}[{i}].{nameof(ValueWithName.Value)}")
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the amount of work you did preparing the code samples! Unfortunately, I can't use columns auto-generation because the real model contains some properties that should not be shown in the DataGrid but are needed for some bindings, therefore AutoGenerateColumns is set to false in my case. Still, I was able to achieve the goal using part of the code behind sample you wrote, I'll post it in a few moments

Comment: If you take a closer look, you will see that in my example it is explicitly specified for which properties the columns should be created.
For those whose names fall into the switch-default will not be created columns .
Additional columns are created at after of the autogenerated ones in the OnAutoGeneratedColumns method.
Here you can add whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

After some time I've managed to achieve the expected result using blend behaviors and a part of code from EldHasp's answer.

The code may not be the most beautiful but it seems to be working for now. Here's the newly created class:

```
public class DataGridAttachedBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    public IList<ValueWithName> Values
    {
        get => GetValue(FactorsProperty) as IList<ValueWithName>;
        set => SetValue(FactorsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValuesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Values), typeof(IList<ValueWithName>), typeof(DataGridAttachedBehavior));

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        AssociatedObject.LoadingRow += OnLoadingRow;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        AssociatedObject.LoadingRow -= OnLoadingRow;
    }

    private void AddValuesColumns()
    {
        if (Values == null || !Values.Any())
            return;

        var columns = AssociatedObject.Columns;
        var headers = columns.Select(c => c.Header is TextBlock tb ? tb.Text : c.Header?.ToString());

        for (int i = 0; i < Values.Count; i++)
        {
            ValueWithName item = Values[i];

            if (headers.Contains(item.Name))
                continue;

            columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
            {
                Header = item.Name,
                Binding = new Binding($"{nameof(MainData.NestedData)}[{i}].{nameof(ValueWithName.Value)}")
            });
        }
    }

    private void OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        AddValuesColumns();
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddValuesColumns();
    }
}
```

There was only a small addition to the view:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <local:DataGridAttachedBehavior Values="{Binding DataCollection/NestedData}" />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The rest did not require any changes.

Comment: Behavior - is the best method.
I didn't do that because I wanted to shorten the example.