# How to make My List of Model work like DataTable on DataGrid Control of WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I got to have one question about the auto generating column function of wpf data grid.
As you may already know, when we use a data table as an itemsource like

```
this.datagrid.ItemsSource = table.AsDataView();
```

we can see the data grid make columns according to table's columns.
But When I use my own list of data model, I get stuck.
My model class is like below

```
public class MyDataGridModel
{
   private object[] _itemArray;

   public object[] ItemArray
   {
      get { return _itemArray; }
      set { _itemArray = value; }
   }

    public MyDataGridModel(List<string> data)
    {
       ItemArray = data.ToArray();
    }
 }
```

Populating a data grid with a list of MyDataGridModel doesn't work.
It just make one column named "ItemArray", not many columns as much as number of data in ItemArray

So, My question is that there is any interface or some magic method to make my model work like data table.

**Update**

It seemed that there was a unclear thing on my question.
I tried like below and xaml for a datagrid only set AutoGenerateColumn property to true.

**For DataTable**

```
List<string> data = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("col1");
table.Columns.Add("col2");
table.Columns.Add("col3");
table.Rows.Add(data.ToArray());
table.Rows.Add(data.ToArray());
table.Rows.Add(data.ToArray());
this.datagrid.ItemsSource = table.AsDataView();
```

then the the datagrid showed that three columns each named coll,2,3 and three rows that each has a,b,c

For List of MyDataGridModel

```
List<string> data = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };          
List<MyDataGridModel> data2 = new List<MyDataGridModel>();            
data2.Add(new MyDataGridModel(data));            
data2.Add(new MyDataGridModel(data));
data2.Add(new MyDataGridModel(data));
this.datagrid.ItemsSource = data2;
```

then the datagrid showed only one column named ItemArray and three rows which have string "String[] Array".

I know that I can see all data in MyDataGridModel if I add some column configuration to a datagrid. But I want to see all data without any specific column configuration, which makes a datagrid be able to use for any length of ItemArray.

I even hope I get to know if it is impossible thing or not

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you doing the binding to the view model?

Comment: @MarkFeldman I updated my question after you commented. thank you

Comment: As I understand it, you want to display a collection of lists.
In general your problem has no solution.
At a minimum, you need some kind of algorithm that determines the required number of columns, if different rows have a different number of elements and if their number changes after the columns are created (i.e. in real time).

Comment: Look at an example of solving a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67100338/datagrid-with-columns-created-dynamically-from-the-items-in-nested-collection/67104698#67104698

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel should be inheriting from INotifyPropertyChanged

Create a new class file called ViewModelBase

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
                                                                        
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Be sure to include the using statements

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
```

Then in your ViewModel

```
public class MyDataGridModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<string> _items;

    public List<string> Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set => Set(ref _items, value);
    }

    public MyDataGridModel(List<string> data)
    {
        Items = data;
    }
}
```

Then in your View set the ItemSource to bind to your Items List, be sure to set the DataContext in your view to the ViewModel

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyDataGridModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

You are only going to get 1 Column as your data type is just of string if you want to display more columns you will need to make a Model with all your properties you wish to display in the datagrid and set the type of string to your Model name then create columns in the datagrid for each property and bind their values to each column.

Hope this is of some help to you.

Comment: I really appreciated your answer. But I'm afraid your answer was not about my problem. So I updated some details. please check it out. And I have come up with a new question on your answer. Is there specific reason you used EqualityComparer in Set funtion?